# position search bar 100% width in CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.brand-container3 {
  background-image: url("media/wysiwyg/576_1.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.search-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-flex;
}

.searchTerm {
  border: 3px solid #556B2F;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAC;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #12291F;
}

.centersearchButton {
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #556B2F;
  background: #556B2F;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
}
    
.centersearchButton:hover {
  background: #6B8E23;  
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
}

.centersearchButton:active {
  background: #6B8E23;  
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;  
}

.centersearchButton:focus, .loader:focus {
    outline: 0;
}    
    
/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.loader {
  border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 10px solid #ffb677; /* #3498db */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: none;   
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
} 

input {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="brand-container3">
  <form id="search_mini_form" action="https://www.cannockgates.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/" method="get" class="wrap" onsubmit="return validateCenterSearch()">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search Products..." id="centersearch" name="q" maxlength="128" value="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" title="Search by Keyword or Product Code">
      <button type="submit" class="centersearchButton" title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i><div class="loader"></div>
</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Dear stackoverflow,

Im trying to get the search bar to fill the width of the screen. The searchbar is currently on top of a background image div container, and i want the search bar to be right in the centre of the parent div container.

I have tried width: 100%; messed with padding and margin. still cannot get my desired results.

Maybe this is a simple fix, however atm. the size of the search bar is fixed.

Comment: you should add ..search-container width:100%.. becoz flex always get auto width

Comment: `.search-container input[type="search"] {
width: calc(100vw - 80px);
}` This works also, damn CSS is still crazy difficult for me lmao

Comment: why you use calc method for this pls explain more. @UrbanOzzy

Comment: Im not too sure myself to be honest, I can either JUST mess with the search container with the above code. or i have to set width: 100% for BOTH .searchterm and .search-container

Comment: can you check your output please.. left side saerch bar little bit hide this is calc issue.. check and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add width:100%; for below class. because flex and inputs  always get auto width

**CSS**

```
.searchTerm {
  border: 3px solid #556B2F;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAC;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:100%;
}
.search-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-flex;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was such a simple fix! Thank you everyone for helping. I think the issue was, because i was changing each class individually. When it didn't work, I just ctrl-z, then tried to change another class. I WILL REMEMBER THIS NEXT TIME <3

Comment: yeah cool... you should always use width 100% for input types

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated code. Give width to input.

```css
.brand-container3 {
  background-image: url("media/wysiwyg/576_1.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.search-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-flex;
}

.search-container input[type="search"] {
width: calc(100vw - 80px);
}

.searchTerm {
  border: 3px solid #556B2F;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAC;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #12291F;
}

.centersearchButton {
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #556B2F;
  background: #556B2F;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
}
    
.centersearchButton:hover {
  background: #6B8E23;  
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
}

.centersearchButton:active {
  background: #6B8E23;  
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;  
}

.centersearchButton:focus, .loader:focus {
    outline: 0;
}    
    
/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.loader {
  border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 10px solid #ffb677; /* #3498db */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: none;   
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
} 

input {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="brand-container3">
  <form id="search_mini_form" action="https://www.cannockgates.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/" method="get" class="wrap" onsubmit="return validateCenterSearch()">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search Products..." id="centersearch" name="q" maxlength="128" value="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" title="Search by Keyword or Product Code">
      <button type="submit" class="centersearchButton" title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i><div class="loader"></div>
</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this works great too, could you explain the `.search-container input[type="search"] {
width: calc(80vw - 80px);
}` I know we messing with the class .search container, but what is the code after it. Sorry, I'm a newbie x